# Check if a date field is a multiple of an intervval in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I have a question about a query in MySQL 5. What I'm looking to do is check a datetime field named created and see if today is an interval of 3 months from that date.

If created is 2013-07-01 12:34 and this query is run daily, the first time this row will be returned is on 2013-10-01, the second time would be on 2014-01-01, etc.

To check if today is exactly X months from created, I'd do this:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE(a.created), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) = CURDATE()
```

I've read through the date/time functions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html but I don't see any functions to do what I'm looking for.

Is there any better or more accurate way to do this then something like:

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(a.created)) % 90 = 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want 3 months, or do you want 90 days?

Comment: 3 months, but I don't think I can use any of the month functions because it will round (int)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,CURDATE(), DATE(a.created)) %3 =0 
    AND DAY(a.created) % DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) = DAY(CURDATE())
```

This ensures that the time difference it 3 months and the date of the month is the same. It also handles the event that the date doesn't exist in that month with the % last_day. For example if the Event was November 30, since there is no feb 30, it will match march 2 or 1 depending on if it is a leap year.